# Unable to customize the primary key pattern in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have 3 models, `Student`, `Course` and `Fee`. I want to create a report which will bring all the data contained by these 3 models, together, with an ID of its own.

**The models:**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CourseChoices(models.Model):
    courses=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.courses

class Course(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    course=models.ForeignKey(CourseChoices, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Fee(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Final_amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Amount_received=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    batch=models.IntegerField()
```

Now, a student may pay his/her fee in installments, so that will create multiple instances in the track report. I want the user to track each transaction with the primary key/id. Below is an example:

[image: Track Report Sample]

I have additional model which brings everything together:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee = models.ForeignKey(Fee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def _get_next_id(self):
        last = Report.objects.all().aggregate(models.Max('id'))['id__max']
        if last:
            last += 1
            self.id = "{}{:04d}".format('HB', last)
        elif not last:
            last = 1
        self.id = "{}{:04d}".format('HB', last)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = self._get_next_id()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The view for Fee:

```
def fee_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_fee=FeeForm(request.POST)
        if fm_fee.is_valid():
            fee=fm_fee.save()
            Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))
            fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
    else:
        fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
```

However, the `id` doesn't get the pattern I intend to give it when I check the database. I assume there is a problem there is some problem in the `_get_next_id` and `save` methods in `Report` model but I'm unable to know it. Would someone here know it? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide how exactly your combined key format should look like ? that will help others to identify the issue and provide solutions according to it.

Comment: It is there in sample track report picture I have posted. An excel table. The first column is how I want my primary key to look like. For eg: HB0001, HB0002 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `id` as an integer field, so the database is not going to store a string there.

It would simplify things if you remove your custom `id` field for the `Report` class and let Django automatically generate a primary key. Then you no longer need the `_get_next_id` method and the overridden `save` method. Instead you can add a `track_id` property to generate an id for reports in your own custom format.

The `Report` class would then look like:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee = models.ForeignKey(Fee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def track_id(self):
        if self.pk:
            return "{}{:04d}".format('HB', self.pk)
        else:
            return ""
```

In your template, you can do this:

```
{% for transaction in reports %}
    ...
    {{ transaction.track_id }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man. It worked well. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: Just have one little doubt. When the track_id reaches 10000, will it throw an error? Because there is only 4 boxes defined in the string format for it. Or will it accommodate any number of digits into it? If not, how can I overcome that issue?

Comment: I just tried it in the python console and it will accommodate any number of digits and won't throw an error. Of course, if you wanted track_id to always be the same width, then you would need to decide on a maximum.

Comment: Okay, sure. Thank you once again. :)